# mongoid with foreverb gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I'm trying to read all records from a mongo document on my rails foreverb daemon, but when I try to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems' unless defined?(Gem)
require 'forever'
require 'mongoid'

Forever.run do

  every 10.seconds do
        @classes = Availability.where(:availability_date.gt => Time.now.utc + 1.hours).to_a
        puts @classes.count
  end

end
```

I always get:

> Do you want really start
>   /Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/script/user/classes_notification.rb?
>   yes
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67:
>   [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883)
>   [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
>
> -- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------    See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
>        * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>        * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>        * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
>        * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports    the more detail of.
>
> -- Control frame information ----------------------------------------------- c:0022 p:---- s:0069 e:000068 CFUNC  :initialize c:0021 p:---- s:0067 e:000066 CFUNC  :new
>   c:0020 p:0075 s:0064 e:000061 METHOD
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67
>   c:0019 p:0070 s:0053 e:000051 CLASS 
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:17
>   c:0018 p:0011 s:0050 e:000049 CLASS 
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:12
>   c:0017 p:0057 s:0048 e:000047 TOP
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:9
>   [FINISH] c:0016 p:---- s:0046 e:000045 CFUNC  :require c:0015 p:0019
>   s:0042 e:000041 CLASS 
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:58
>   c:0014 p:0017 s:0040 e:000039 TOP
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:54
>   [FINISH] c:0013 p:---- s:0038 e:000037 CFUNC  :require c:0012 p:0009
>   s:0034 e:000033 TOP
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:3
>   [FINISH] c:0011 p:---- s:0032 e:000031 CFUNC  :require c:0010 p:0063
>   s:0028 e:000027 TOP
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:10
>   [FINISH] c:0009 p:---- s:0026 e:000025 CFUNC  :require c:0008 p:0025
>   s:0022 e:000021 BLOCK 
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:2
>   [FINISH] c:0007 p:---- s:0019 e:000018 CFUNC  :each c:0006 p:0031
>   s:0016 e:000015 TOP
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:1
>   [FINISH] c:0005 p:---- s:0014 e:000013 CFUNC  :require c:0004 p:0023
>   s:0010 e:000009 TOP
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid.rb:25
>   [FINISH] c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :require c:0002 p:0033
>   s:0004 E:000698 EVAL
>   /Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/script/user/classes_notification.rb:4
>   [FINISH] c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000368 TOP    [FINISH]
>
> /Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/script/user/classes_notification.rb:4:in
>   `<main>'
>   /Users/jeanosorio/repos/blabloo/script/user/classes_notification.rb:4:in`
>   require'
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid.rb:25:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@blabloo/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid.rb:25:in`
>   require'

etc etc etc

So I don't know if is possible to read my mongo db from a daemon using foreverb.

Please some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something's messed up with your ruby install - you're running ruby 2.0 but you're picking up gems built against ruby 1.9.3

Comment: try replace `#!/usr/bin/ruby` with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` this should force shell to pick up setup ruby version.

Comment: thanks @МалъСкрылевъ that solve my problem with the foreverb but now I don't have access to my model I'm getting uninitialized constant Availability (Availability is my model)

Comment: @Jean that means that Avaiable constant is uninialized, i.e. your haven't loaded your file with it.